# How to change the default syntax highlighting for new files in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, markdown, sublimetext, syntax-highlighting, plaintext

When I'm opening a new file (e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>), the default Syntax in Sublime Text 3 is just **Plain Text**. I would like to change that into e.g. **Markdown**. (How) Is that possible?

I would like to avoid a "hacky" solution as [proposed here](https://www.quora.com/Sublime-Text-How-can-I-change-default-syntax-to-html):

> creat a file in your Packages/User directory called
>   'default_syntax.py' or something, and add this:
>
> ```
> import sublime, sublime_plugin
>
> class DefaultSyntaxCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
>    def on_new(self, view):
>       view.set_syntax_file('Packages/HTML/HTML.tmLanguage')
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible with the [ApplySyntax](http://facelessuser.github.io/ApplySyntax) Plugin. Once it is installed (e.g. via [PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io)), you can set the ApplySyntax User Settings like that:

```
"new_file_syntax": "Markdown/MultiMarkdown",
```

or

```
"new_file_syntax": "Markdown/Markdown",
```

depending on your installed Markdown syntax. Now if you open a new file, your default syntax will be Markdown.

Comment: Will this treat every file as `Markdown` regardless of content?

Comment: This will treat every **new** file as `Markdown`